# Get child of element and wrap?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have some HTML that goes like this?

```
<article class="post">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="368" valign="top"><p> ONDERDEEL</p></td>
          <td width="350" valign="top"><p> BEGELEIDER/VERANTWOORDELIJKE</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="368" valign="top"><p> Evaluatiemomenten</p></td>
          <td width="350" valign="top"><p> P-manager</p></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</article>
```

What i need is to get all tables inside article and wrap it with new class .jobs-table
Then the final html has to look like this

```
<article class="post">
  <div class="jobs-table">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="368" valign="top"><p> ONDERDEEL</p></td>
          <td width="350" valign="top"><p> BEGELEIDER/VERANTWOORDELIJKE</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="368" valign="top"><p> Evaluatiemomenten</p></td>
          <td width="350" valign="top"><p> P-manager</p></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</article>
```

All this i have to do by jquery because i use CMS and user wants that cms control styling, the problem is that i can do this by css because user enters content by tinymce, that way he controls the look, only want tables to be all the same

For now i have jquery

```
$("table").removeAttr("style");
$("td").removeAttr("width");
```

Comment: I'm sure your will find your answer if you google for `jquery wrap`.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/LsKnc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it like this:

```
$('.post table').each(function(){
   $('.post').wrap('<div class="jobs-table" />');
});
```

Comment: I want only to wrap inside article

Comment: This will wrap all .posts multiple times.

Comment: @Schneider: then why is the div outside of article in your question?

Comment: Sorry i didnt see, i have fixed

Answer (score 1):

Use `.wrap()` - Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

Try this

```
$('article.post').wrap( "<div class='jobs-table'></div>" );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LAH6L/3/)

Answer (score 0):

wrap method grab your table by div

```
$('table').wrap("<div class='jobs-table'></div>");
```